# Is there a way to implement two pipes continuously in a c program using fork and exec?

Tags: c, operating-system

What I mean is, can I use `fork()` and `exec()` to implement calls like:
`ls -l | wc | wc` , where I have used 2 pipes.

Comment: YEs, you can. The shell is written in C, and it does it.

Comment: Call `pipe` twice to set up the two pipes, call `fork` three times, connect all the pipes to the appropriate `stdin` and `stdout` with `dup2`, and then `exec` the programs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to chain your forks and execs [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082932/connecting-n-commands-with-pipes-in-a-shell#answer-8092270) for an example of pipe chaining.

You'll have to use [dup(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) to duplicate the `stdout` of one process to the `stdin` of the next process in the chain.

Comment: If you're just going to refer him to another question, vote to close as a duplicatae.

Comment: @Barmar was in the process of doing that as this comment popped up