# What is the difference between these two pointer declarations?

Tags: c, posix, pipeline

Are these declarations different or do the produce the same result?

```
char * const *argv;
```

and

```
const char **argv;
```

Is there a difference or are both pointer to a pointer?

The background is that I was writing a C commandline shell and used this struct for a command:

```
struct command
{
    char * const *argv;
};
```

The above struct was used to call `exec`. Now when I looked at another question then the struct was different:

[Connecting n commands with pipes in a shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082932/connecting-n-commands-with-pipes-in-a-shell)

In that question the struct to achieve the same is different.

Comment: [This entry in the C-faq](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constptrconst.html) may help (plus a bit of extrapolation to your case).

Comment: @Shripada There are no arrays in the code shown. Only pointers.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char)

Comment: I'm curious about one thing. Did you really meant this ==>> `const char **argv;` or you meant this ==>> `const char *argv;`?

Comment: @Michi I'm going to try and add some background to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are totally different:

`char *const *argv;` declares "a pointer to **const** pointer to char";

`const char **argv;` declares "a pointer to pointer to **const** char";

Also, `char **const argv;` declares "a **const** pointer to pointer to char".

To understand these declarations, try reading them "inside out": http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html

Comment: It could be that the Answer  is based on a mistyping. I think he meant `const char *argv;`. One less star :)