# Using Pipe in C, yes | head is going in an infinite loop

Tags: c, pipe, dup2

Following this SO question & answer

[Connecting n commands with pipes in a shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082932/connecting-n-commands-with-pipes-in-a-shell)

I tried executing `yes | head` but it runs in an infinite loop or it never responds back. What is the issue.

I did made some changes and here is the running code

```
#include <unistd.h>

struct command
{
    const char **string;
};
```

Helper Function

```
pid_t start(command* command, pid_t pid, int* status, int in, int out) {
    (void) pid;
    pid_t cpid;
    int childInt;

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == 0) {

        if (in != 0)
        {
            dup2(in, 0);
            close(in);
        }


        if (out != 1)
        {
            dup2(out, 1);
            close(out);
        }

            execvp(c->string[0], c->string);
            _exit(1);
        }

        waitpid(cpid, &childInt, 0);
    }


    *status = childInt;
    return c->pid;
}
```

and in my main function

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //New command every loop
    int p = pipe(fd);
    if (p == 0)
    {
        start_command(c, 0, &status, in, fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    continue;
}
dup2(in, 0);
```

Comment: What is your question? You might take another look at your code and put together a [mcve] that compiles.

Comment: your *start_command* waits for the command's completion... so ask yourself if you do `yes` and wait for *its* completion (which it never does since you're keeping the other end of the pipe open)... and never even get to executing `head`

Comment: Code works fine. The error lied in reading the file from where i was reading the commands to execute. Caught me completely off guard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to execute `yes | head`, you need to create two processes, `yes` and `head`, and you need to connect them with a pipe. You have no code to do that, you just execute `yes` and pass it `| head`. This causes `yes` to output `"| head"` over and over forever.

You can't just pass `yes` and `| head` to `execvp`. You could `execvp` a shell and pass it `yes | head` since shells have the necessary code to create pipelines, spawn multiple processes, and hook them up appropriately.

Comment: I was trying to implement shell pipeline in my code so executing it together kills the purpose. So are you saying I should not use execvp?

Comment: I think I understand. I am executing first before starting another pipe exec. Need to start the child first then the parent.

Comment: @BasitAnwer You need to create the pipe first!