# When implementing the pipe command in C++, I failed to redirect input from pipe to STDIN_FILENO using `dup2` in the child process

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, execvp, dup2

I want to implement pipe command in shell, such as `ls | cat | wc`. Here's my pipe command implementation.

I use a pipe to store the results generated by every command. For every child process, it:

- obtain input from the pipe (generated by the last command)
- redirect stdout to pipe
- call `execvp` to execute the command with the input

Here's my code:

```cpp
while(getline(std::cin, s)) {
    if(s == "exit") {
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    // initialize a pipe
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe creation failed!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    // split the command into multiple parts
    vector<string> tokens;
    boost::algorithm::split(tokens, s, boost::is_any_of("|"),boost::token_compress_on);
    for(auto& command: tokens) {
        // prepare to run the current command
    
        // get the current command
        boost::algorithm::trim(command);
        // split the command into an array of args
        vector<string> args;
        boost::algorithm::split(args,command,boost::is_any_of(" "),boost::token_compress_on);
        int argc = args.size();
        if(argc < 1) {
            cerr << "We need a command!" << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE; 
        }
    
        // run the current command
        pid_t child = fork();
        if(child == 0) {
            // setup the file name and input arguments
            const char* filename = args[0].c_str();
            char** argv = new char*[argc + 1];
            for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                string args_str = args[i];
                argv[i] = new char[10];
                strcpy(argv[i],args_str.c_str());
            }
            argv[argc] = nullptr;
    
            // write the pipe value into stdin
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd[0]);
    
            // write stdout to the pipe
            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd[1]);
    
            // use execvp() to run the commmand
            execvp(filename,argv);
    
            // exec didn't work, so an error must have been occurred
            cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
            delete[] argv;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        
        // wait for the child process to complete
        int status;
        waitpid(child,&status,0);
    }
    // read out the pipe
    char* buffer = new char[BUF_SIZ];
    int count = read(fd[0],buffer,BUF_SIZ);
    if(count > 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
    }
    
    delete buffer;        
    
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    cout << "$ ";

}
```

When I test the program by entering `ls | cat`. The last command successfully put the result of `ls` into the pipe. But I could not redirect input from pipe to STDIN_FILENO when executing the `cat` command.

The program just blocks when executing `ls | cat`. After debugging, I found that it's because the `cat` command is still waiting for user to input something, and the parent process is waiting for the child process to terminate.

Comment: What you're doing right now in the child process is connecting standard output to standard input. You should not duplicate `fd[0]`, only close it.

Comment: On a different note, replace `char* buffer = new char[BUF_SIZ];` (and it's deletion which you use the wrong operator for) with `char buffer[BUF_SIZE];`.

Comment: Oh and by the way, you might not be able to read everything with just a single `read` call. And `read` will not null-terminate the buffer, and neither will the output from the child process.

Comment: To explain the problem with the loop between standard output and standard input in the child process, what happens of the child process tries to read from standard input before it writes to standard output? Then it will block, waiting for input that never comes.

Comment: The way to make a pipe work is to redirect standard output from the first program to the pipe, and the standard input from the pipe for the second program. So output from `ls` goes through the pipe, and the input to `cat` comes from the pipe. The input for `ls` is still the normal standard input, and the output of `cat` is not piped but just the normal standard output.

Comment: So I should use `fork()` and create 2 child process? The 1st process: STDIN -> `execvp` -> STDOUT -> pipe. The 2nd process: pipe -> STDIN -> `execvp` -> STDOUT.

Comment: Yes, you need two child processes, one for each program in the pipe-line.

Comment: Excuse me, but I have another question. In the program above, I want to achieve the process `pipe -> STDIN -> execvp -> STDOUT -> pipe` to implement a sequence of pipes. Why did you say that the STDOUT is connected to STDIN?  I previously thought that the `dup2` command just changes where the file descriptor points to, so I declared that the `STDIN` comes from `fd[0]` and the `STDOUT` goes to `fd[1]` before executing `execvp`, but I didn't know that the `STDOUT` and `STDIN` are directly connected in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who raised this question. Now I've worked out the problem now and successfully implemented the multi-pipe program. I made 3 changes to the previous code:

1. In the previous code, there's only one pipe. What I previously intended to do is achieve the process `pipe -> STDIN -> execvp -> STDOUT -> pipe`. But if I only use 1 pipe, the `STDIN` and `STDOUT` are connected. So In the current version of my program, I create a new pipe before `fork()` and close its write end, but I record its read end in a variable `fd_in`.
2. The variable `fd_in` is set to 0 at first. Because some commands such as `cat` need to obtain input from the `STDIN` instead of pipe. After each command execution, the `fd_in` is updated to the current pipe's read end for the next command execution. While working with this problem, I found that pipe is not the same as local variable, which is pushed on the stack on process memory. It's stored in kernel memory rather than the process memory, so the created pipe won't go away immediately after the loop exits. But if we declares a local variable in a loop, it's gone after the loop exits. If we record the read end of the pipe, we could still reach it in the next loop.
3. I use a variable `count` and compare it to the length of command vector in order to determine if it is the last command to execute. If it is not the last command, write the result to the pipe. Otherwise, just print out the result to the console. Therefore, there's no need to use the system call `read` to get the result out of pipe and store it in a buffer in the parent process. It's mainly for those command which print out results to the console immediately, such as `cat`. Besieds, it simplify the design.

The new version of code as follows:

```cpp
    while (getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        if (s == "exit")
        {
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        int fd[2];
        int in_fd = 0; // input fd

        // split the command into multiple parts
        vector<string> tokens;
        boost::algorithm::split(tokens, s, boost::is_any_of("|"), boost::token_compress_on);

        int count = 1;
        int command_num = tokens.size();

        for (auto &command : tokens)
        {
            // initialize a pipe
            if (pipe(fd) == -1)
            {
                perror("pipe creation failed!");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            // prepare to run the current command

            // get the current command
            boost::algorithm::trim(command);
            // split the command into an array of args
            vector<string> args;
            boost::algorithm::split(args, command, boost::is_any_of(" "), boost::token_compress_on);
            int argc = args.size();
            if (argc < 1)
            {
                cerr << "We need a command!" << endl;
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            // run the current command
            pid_t child = fork();
            if (child == 0)
            {
                // setup the file name and input arguments
                const char *filename = args[0].c_str();
                char **argv = new char *[argc + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
                {
                    string args_str = args[i];
                    argv[i] = new char[10];
                    strcpy(argv[i], args_str.c_str());
                }
                argv[argc] = nullptr;

                if (in_fd != 0)
                {
                    // write the pipe value into stdin
                    dup2(in_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
                    close(in_fd);
                }

                if (count != command_num)
                {
                    // write stdout to the pipe
                    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(fd[1]);
                }

                // use execvp() to run the commmand
                execvp(filename, argv);

                // exec didn't work, so an error must have been occurred
                cerr << strerror(errno) << endl;
                delete[] argv;
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            // wait for the child process to complete
            int status;
            waitpid(child, &status, 0);

            // close the current pipe write fd
            close(fd[1]);
            in_fd = fd[0];
            count += 1;
        }

        // // read out the pipe
        // char buffer[BUF_SIZ];
        // int count = read(in_fd, buffer, BUF_SIZ);
        // buffer[count] = '\0';
        // if (count > 0)
        // {
        //     fprintf(stdout, "%s", buffer);
        // }
        close(in_fd);

        cout << "$ ";
    }
```

Thanks for [Some programmmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)'s help. And I refer to an answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082932/connecting-n-commands-with-pipes-in-a-shell) in the process of solving this question. I hope my implementation will give you some inspirations.